# Laravel checkbox validation, always empty?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation, laravel-5.5

I have a checkboxes like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div style="display:none ;" class="weekday_message form-control alert-warning"></div>
  <label id="weekday2" for="weekday" class="col-md-4 control-label">Weekday</label>
  <div class="required form-field" name="weekday" id="weekday">
    <input class="weekday" type="checkbox" name="weekdays[]" value="MO">Monday
    <input class="weekday" type="checkbox" name="weekdays[]" value="TU">Tuesday
    <input class="weekday" type="checkbox" name="weekdays[]" value="WE">Wednesday
    <input class="weekday" type="checkbox" name="weekdays[]" value="TH">Thursday
    <input class="weekday" type="checkbox" name="weekdays[]" value="FR">Friday
    <input class="weekday" type="checkbox" name="weekdays[]" value="SA">Saturday
    <input class="weekday" type="checkbox" name="weekdays[]" value="SU">Sunday
  </div>
    <span class="help-block">
        <strong></strong>
</span>
  </div>
```

My validation:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'startdate' => 'required|date',
            'endate' => 'nullable|date',
            'startime' => ['required', new Time],
            'endtime' => ['required', new Time],
            'title' => 'required',
            'entity_id' => 'required',
            'type' => 'required|exists:entities,type',
            'description' => 'required',
            'frequency' => 'required',
            'interval' => 'nullable|numeric',
            'monthday' => 'nullable|numeric|min:1|max:3',
            'weekdays' => 'array|max:3',
            'month' => 'nullable|numeric',
            'until' => 'nullable|date',
            'tags' => 'nullable',
        ];
    }
```

and controller:

```
public function storeEvent(EventRequest $request)
{
    $test = ($request->input('weekdays'));
    dd($test);
    $weekday_string = implode(",", $request->input('weekdays'));
    $request->merge(array('weekday', $weekday_string));
    dd($request->all());
    $event = DirtyEvent::create($request->all());
    $geoloc_id = Entity::find($event->entity_id)
        ->first();
    $user_id = Auth::id();
    // Save Geoloc + user id into newly created event
    $event->_geoloc()->associate($geoloc_id);
    $event->users()->associate($user_id);
    $event->save();
```

Now, validation seems to pass because it does data dump, however both dd($test) as well as $request->all() are giving me back empty weekdays, like it would not be defined. What could be the possible cause of this?

Comment: Do you have any of the checkboxes checked in your form? As far as I know, an unchecked checkbox is not passed to Request input.

Comment: ofc I have, I checked all of them during the form process

Comment: Your HTML says `weekday` (singular) but in your rules set is as `weekdays` (plural). I added this to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure you have always at least one weekday selected you should change:

```
'weekdays' => 'array|max:3',
```

into:

```
'weekdays' => 'array|required|max:3',
```

Also I suppose you don't send data using standard HTML form because you set for example name for divs so maybe you forget to attach weekdays or have bug in code elsewhere?

Comment: I am sending them using ajax, the thing is I tried to do it as 'required' and funny thing is it was not returning any errors

Comment: So look at your browser console and verify what exactly is sent. How do you know it's not returning any validation errors? You verified it already in console?

Comment: I am however doing form.serialize in ajax, data: that might be the cause?

Comment: Hard to say. Look at your console and verify what exact data you are sending into your backend.

Comment: and yes, I have verified and if I remove dd($test) I get dd of $request->all but just without weekdays[]

Comment: If you don't have required rule this is normal - when you don't send it validation will pass when you don't send weekdays at all

Comment: What is "EventRequest" that you used as type hint? Is it a custom model? I checked your code and everything works with "Request" instead of "EventRequest".

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML says `weekday` (singular) but your rules set says `weekdays` (plural).

There needs to be at least one checkbox selected to make the input `weekdays` to be included in the request. You can use a default value in case none was selected by adding a hidden input before the checkboxes.

```
<input type="hidden" name="weekdays" value="defaultValue">
```